# How exclude items with relationship null

Tags: laravel, eloquent, group-by

I have a relationship in eloquent query and should group items by value from relation.
After groupBy I have items with relation === null. How get list of items with out relation === null after groupBy. (laravel version 8)
Code of relation

[image: Code of relation]

Response

[image: response]

Comment: Welcome to SO.  [Please do not post images of code/error messages.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use
`whereHas('networkType')` instead of `with()`